# r: nested for-loop only generates NA when summarizing output

Tags: r, dataframe, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I am new to for loops.

I am using survival data, let's say:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(riskRegression)
data(Melanoma)
```

My nested for loop should:

- re-allocate a *random* sample in a total `i`-times
- the random sample comprise `j`-percentage of the entire `Melanoma`-data

Explanation:

A Cox regression may be written like:

```
coxph(Surv(time, status == 1) ~ ici + age, data = Melanoma)
```

Consider

```
table(Melanoma$ici)

  0   1   2   3 
 17  59 107  22
```

I want to investigate how the Cox regression is affected if we allocate different percentages (eg. 5% and 10% - the `j`) of `Melanoma$ici == 3` to `Melanoma$ici == 4` using a random sampling i'th times (`i`).

Basically I want to loop this code (note `j`) with a new `set.seed()` in `i`-times

```
Melanoma_new$new_ici[sample(which(Melanoma_new$new_ici == 3), round(j * length(which(Melanoma_new$new_ici == 3))))] = 4
```

Create vectors for the loop

```
nr <- c()
auc_baseline <- c()
auc_new <- c()
delta_auc <- c()
auc_p_contrast <- c()
all_brier <- c()
```

Here's what I have, but that does not work:

```
for(j in seq(0.05, 0.1, 0.05)){ ### the proportion that should be chosen for random sampling
  
  for(i in 1:3){
    Melanoma_new <- Melanoma %>%
      mutate(ici = as.numeric(ici),
             new_ici = as.numeric(ici)) 
    
    set.seed(i) ### set new random samlping  
    
    Melanoma_new$ici[sample(which(Melanoma_new$ici == 3), round(j * length(which(Melanoma_new$ici == 3))))] = 4
    
    ith_cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status == 1) ~ ici + age, data = Melanoma_new, x = TRUE)
    ith_cox_new <- coxph(Surv(time, status == 1) ~ new_ici + age, data = Melanoma_new, x = TRUE)
    
    u_i <- Score(list("baseline" = ith_cox,
                      "newWHO" = ith_cox_new),
                 Surv(time, status == 1) ~ 1,
                 data = Melanoma_new,
                 times = c(300, 600),
                 plots = "cal",
                 B = 100,
                 seed = 1,
                 split.method = "loob",
                 metrics = c("auc", "brier")
    )
    
    ### NOT SURE ON THIS PART
    nr[i] <- i          
    auc_baseline[i] <- u_i$AUC$score$AUC
    auc_new[i] <- u_i$AUC$score$AUC
    delta_auc[i] <- u_i$AUC$contrasts$delta.AUC
    auc_p_contrast[i] <- u_i$AUC$contrasts$p
    all_brier[i] <- u_i$Brier$score$Brier
  }
}
```

Finally I want to write a dataframe that looks like this:

```
data.frame(
  seed_i = nr, #write what i / seed_nr that was used to generate this estimate
  perc_j = #not sure what to write, but I want to know what j was used here in obtaining this estimate
  AUC_baseline = auc_baseline*100,
  AUC_new = auc_new*100,
  Best_AUC = ifelse(auc_baseline > auc_new, "Baseline", "New"),
  AUC_p = ifelse(auc_p_contrast < 0.05, sprintf("%.05f", round(auc_p_contrast, digits = 5)), "")
)
```

**EDIT**
So I figured out that the `NA` probably was related to setting Score::times too low, I have changed it to `times = c(300, 600)`.
I will therefore direct this topic to the subtle question I asked in terms of storing the results. As you can see, I am currently storing my results in vectors that later use to generate a `data.frame`. I need to store the following from the for-loop: `u_i$AUC$score$AUC`, `u_i$AUC$contrasts$delta.AUC`, `u_i$AUC$contrasts$p`, and the `i`'th seed that generated the AUC in Score, and the corresponding `j`'th percentage.

Comment: The `i` and `j` in the name `melanoma_ij` do not change as the variables `i` and `j` change in the loop. (Just like if I define `n <- 2` and `mean <- 5`, the object `mea2` isn't created... it's good that letters in names don't suddenly change.) You need to create a `list`, say `results <- list()` before the loop, and inside the loop you can assign to list items, e.g., `results[[paste0("j", j, ";i", i)]] <- Melanoma...`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. The `_ij` suffix was just a name that I chose. I did not intend to store results in the name. I have changed the name to `Melanoma_new` to avoid this misunderstanding, but the question remain the same.

Comment: There is some error in your call to `Score` as it returns all `NaN`s. This does not seem to be a programming error, but a methodological problem.
Besides that, the values that you are saving (`u_i$AUC$score$AUC` etc) all seem to be vectors, not single values. That means you have to change your storage (`auc_new` etc) to type `list`. Create with `auc_new <- list()` instead of `auc_new <- c()`.

Comment: Hi @GregorThomas and @AEF, as you can see, I figured out that the `NA` probably was related to the `times`-argument. I therefore editted the question, and I think you perhaps can help here. I ask for a more efficient way to store the output from the for-loop other than saving the estimates in vectors and then use the vectors for a data.frame. Can you show me how you wuld extract the results to a list? I specified in the updated question what parameters that I am interested in. Thanks!! Happy to accpect a good response as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about functionalisation?  Does this give what you want?

```
# Also need to call survival
library(tidyverse)
library(riskRegression)
library(survival)
data(Melanoma)

# Produce a function that outputs the list of parameters
  cox_reg_function <- function(j, i) {
    Melanoma_new <- Melanoma %>%
      mutate(ici = as.numeric(ici),
             new_ici = as.numeric(ici)) 
    
    set.seed(i) ### set new random samlping  
    
    Melanoma_new$ici[sample(which(Melanoma_new$ici == 3), round(j * length(which(Melanoma_new$ici == 3))))] = 4
    
    ith_cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status == 1) ~ ici + age, data = Melanoma_new, x = TRUE)
    ith_cox_new <- coxph(Surv(time, status == 1) ~ new_ici + age, data = Melanoma_new, x = TRUE)
    
    u_i <- Score(list("baseline" = ith_cox,
                      "newWHO" = ith_cox_new),
                 Surv(time, status == 1) ~ 1,
                 data = Melanoma_new,
                 times = c(300, 600),
                 plots = "cal",
                 B = 100, 
                 seed = 1,
                 split.method = "loob",
                 metrics = c("auc", "brier")
    )
    
    out <- tibble(prop = j, # Keep track of the inputs across the iterations
                  seed = i, # ditto
                  auc_new = u_i$AUC$score$AUC, 
                  delta_auc = u_i$AUC$contrasts$delta.AUC, 
                  auc_p_contrast = u_i$AUC$contrasts$p, 
                  all_brier = u_i$Brier$score$Brier)
    
    return(out)
  }

# Build dataframe of probabilities and seeds
  df <- expand_grid(j = seq(0.05, 0.1, 0.05), i = 1:3)

# Run function against each combination
  out <- map2_dfr(df$j, df$i, cox_reg_function)


 > out
# A tibble: 36 × 6
    prop  seed auc_new delta_auc auc_p_contrast all_brier
   <dbl> <int>   <dbl>     <dbl>          <dbl>     <dbl>
 1  0.05     1   0.410   0.00105         0.986     0.0300
 2  0.05     1   0.394   0.00851         0.888     0.0482
 3  0.05     1   0.411   0.00745         0.0686    0.0302
 4  0.05     1   0.437   0.0425          0.488     0.0489
 5  0.05     1   0.419   0.0544          0.379     0.0302
 6  0.05     1   0.449   0.0119          0.0108    0.0488
 7  0.05     2   0.410   0.0109          0.857     0.0300
 8  0.05     2   0.394   0.00851         0.888     0.0482
 9  0.05     2   0.421  -0.00242         0.607     0.0301
10  0.05     2   0.436   0.0421          0.455     0.0487
# … with 26 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

NB I applied fewer cycles to speed up the process, so values may vary to the actual output

Comment: I didn't include the lines for running the function across different iterations.  Included in the edited Answer